# How to add extra checkout step in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkout-page

I am trying to add extra step in Magento checkout but it is not working at all. I don't know what the wrong I am doing.

Here is what I have done so far.

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="2.0.1">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
    </sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/composer.json**

```
{
"name": "Vendor/ModuleName",
"description": "my description.",
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "2.0.1",
"license": [
"OSL-3.0",
"AFL-3.0"
 ],
"require": {
"php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
"magento/framework": "~100.0.4",
"magento/module-checkout": "~2.0.0"
 },
 "authors": [
 {
  "name": "nFusion Solutions",
  "email": "support@example.com",
  "homepage": "http://example.com/",
  "role": "Developer"
 }
],
"autoload": {
"files": [ "registration.php" ],
"psr-4": {
  "Vendor\\ModuleName\\": ""
  }
}
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view/my-step-view.js**

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    *
    * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template, 
    * Vendor_ModuleName  - is the name of your module directory.
    * 
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_ModuleName/mystep'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
        *
        * @returns {*}
        */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                'step_code',
                //step alias
                null,
                //step title value
                'Step Title',
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                15
            );

            return this;
        },
        navigate: function () {

        },
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
);
```

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/template/mystep.html**

```
  <li id="step_code" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
  <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Step Title'" data-role="title"></div>
   <div id="checkout-step-title"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content">

    <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</li>
```

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view/my-step-view</item>
                                                <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                                <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                                <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

I tried above code but extra step is not adding. What I am doing wrong?
I am using Magento 2.0.5 version

Answer (score 1):

Check your file **`app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`**

```
 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view/my-step-view</item>
```

This should be like below

```
 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName/js/view/my-step-view</item>
```

Comment: Not quite right, shouldn't it be: `Vendor_ModuleName/js/my-step-view` ?  Note the underscore and the removal of 'view' from the path.

Comment: I updated my answer..referred from Magento http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html