# How to add input fields in custom checkout step in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, checkout-page

I have created a module to add a custom checkout step by following the answer
mentioned in this link.
    [How to add new steps or tab to checkout page in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93283/how-to-add-new-steps-or-tab-to-checkout-page-in-magento2)

Here is the screen shot of this step.

[image]

Kindly let me know what to do to add two input fields in this step.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Magento has official document for this and its pretty well explained there.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

there are many tutorilas available to do your stuff.

You can refer this also.

[How to add extra checkout step in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166145/how-to-add-extra-checkout-step-in-magento-2)

Comment: As shown in screen shot i have already added the new step. I just wanted to add input fields in it.

Comment: Add the html template in js and in that html u can put your input fields.. If foow the document properly it pretty clear there

Comment: It is not clear since form is retrieved dynamically using knockout. To add a new field is trivial in the form in the traditional way, but it is better to use the Magento 2 way and knockoutjs. For example,  what if I need to get a customer attribute data in one of the steps?